# Difference between cast(T)x and to!T(x)

Tags: casting, type-conversion, d

What is the difference between `cast(T)x` and `to!T(x)` in D programming language? (provided that the module `std.conv` is imported)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cast(T)x` does a few types of conversions as guaranteed by the language. These include:

- dynamic casts converting between class / interface types, provided by the runtime
- numeric type casts, eg double to short
- array type casts, eg int[] to ubyte[]
- forcing an `alias this` conversion that would otherwise not be forced
- type system-only conversions, especially around `const` and `shared`

`to!T(x)` does a number of other conversions, most notably to and from strings.

Comment: Also, `to` is always `@safe` as it will copy if the cast wouldn't be safe (e.g. from immutable to mutable), so in doubt go with `to` when you don't want a dynamic cast, but a mere conversion between types.